# Library or Technique to scan OS for network traffic

Tags: linux, macos, network-programming, network-traffic

**In short**: in search for a library (or techniques) for capturing http/https/ftp traffic. To be used with C#/Mono or Java, needs to run on Windows/Mac/Linux.

**The long story**: For a given usecase I need to log network traffic (basic from IP to IP does not suffice, I need the actual requests). The method(s) used are fired every 5 seconds to scan for given network activity on the system, and then logs this to file/server/... What I'm after is a library that can output the traffic for each major platform (Windows, Linux, Mac). Current codebase is C# on Mono, but I'm open to switch to Java if need be. I'm also willing to get libraries for each OS seperately, it doesn't have to be one-to-rule-them-all - but currently I haven't been able to see a library or tehcnique that can pull the information out for Linux or Mac - Windows is no problem so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to develop your program using Java [Jpcap](http://jpcap.sourceforge.net/) would be a nice solution. Its capabilities are comparable to those of the well-known [libpcap](http://sourceforge.net/projects/libpcap/).